Associate sharex=True and different hspace between plots
In the following code, I want to add some vertical space between the top and middle plots, and keep zero space between middle and bottom plots.
With a sharex=True between all plot.
Any hint ?
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt, matplotlib as mpl

ii = np.arange(100)

fig, axs = plt.subplots (nrows=3, sharex=True, height_ratios=[1, 2, 3])
plt.subplots_adjust (hspace=0)

axs[0].plot (ii)
axs[1].plot (ii+2)
axs[2].plot (ii*2)


Related: Multiple titles in legend in matplotlib

One option is to add another "dummy" Axes instance where you want the space between subplots to exist, with the appropriate height defined in your height_ratios kwarg, and then remove the Axes using .remove().
For example:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt, matplotlib as mpl

ii = np.arange(100)

fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=4, sharex=True, height_ratios=[1, 0.5, 2, 3])
plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0)

axs[0].plot(ii)
axs[1].remove()
axs[2].plot(ii+2)
axs[3].plot(ii*2)

Here I define the space as half of the top Axes instance, but you can modify that (the second value, 0.5, in height_ratios) to suit your needs.

